# Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process with additional diminishing drift

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am interested in the long-term behavior of the following OU type multivariate process:
$$
dX(t) = \{-H(t)\cdot X(t) - \alpha(t)\mathbf{1}\}dt + \sigma(t)dB(t)
$$
where $\alpha(t) = t^{-c}$ with $c>0$, and $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of 1's with same dimension as $X(t)$. Suppose $H(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ are deterministic positive definite and symmetric (for all $t$) matrices. $B(t)$ is a standard multivariate Brownian motion. As $t\to\infty$, is it true that $X(t)$ has the same stationary distribution as 
$$
d\tilde X(t) = -H(t)\cdot \tilde X(t)dt + \sigma(t)dB(t),
$$
or do $X(t)$ and $\tilde X(t)$ converge to the same *distribution* as $t\to\infty$? Intuitively, this seems to be true, because $\alpha(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.

A major difficulty here is that the matrix $H(t)$ is time-varying in a general way. In particular, both its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are time-varying. It seems difficult to solve the SDEs (at least usual textbook methods won't apply), and compare the solutions.

I would appreciate if anybody could share an idea on how to rigorously prove this, or provides any reference for this. Thank you!

**Edit** (clarify the difficulty, and respond the comment of UBM): if $H(t)$ is a constant matrix $H(t)=H$, and $H$ is positive definite and symmetric, one can see that by solving the first and the second SDE (WLOG suppose $X(0)=\tilde X(0)=0$), 
$$
X(t) = -\int_0^t e^{-H(t-s)} t^{-c} \mathbf{1} ds + \int_0^t e^{-H(t-s)} \sigma(s) dB(s),
$$
while the solution $\tilde X(t)$ does not have the first term on the right hand side. Therefore, one only has to show the first term on the right hand side vanishes as $t\to\infty$ whenever $c>0$, which can be done by careful estimation.

When $H(t)$ is not a constant matrix, I don't think one can solve $X(t)$ and $\tilde X(t)$ nicely.

Comment: There are mild solutions possible of the type you are looking for, but I only know them in the case of SPDEs (but your problem is of course also a simple SPDE), see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.10016.pdf. It might be a bit technical and you will need assumptions on $H(t)$.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into the reference of that paper, and some books are particularly useful. E.g. Chap. 3.4-3.9 of "A. Yagi. Abstract Parabolic Evolution Equations and their Applications. Springer, 2010." Though it describes the system without diffusion, the techniques should apply. I will have a better look.